# why is git creating files with wrong permissions?

Tags: linux, git, jenkins

I'm hoping someone could help with this:

I have a user: jenkins-user with a umask 0002 so that files are created with 664 as shown

```
touch 1.txt
-rw-rw-r--.  1 jenkins-user admin      0 Oct 14 12:04 1.txt
```

However, when the jenkins-user runs [from within jenkins] and does a

```
git pull
```

as part of a build, created files are with different permissions 644 [as shown]

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins-user admin   318 Oct 14  12:18 2.txt
```

and the build log also indicates ... create mode 100644 .....

I understand that git does not interfere with set permissions and only knows whether or not a file is executable, so I am not sure what is messing with the expected permissions, and more importantly, how to rectify this. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: How is your umask configured?  In your shell's startup configuration?  If so, jenkins won't know that, since it's not starting an interactive shell.  You can try running git from the shell (as jenkins-user) to see that it will obey the umask.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: thanks, the umask is set on the servers but I'd try your suggestion and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
git config core.sharedRepository 0660
```

at the server repo. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresharedRepository).

Comment: thanks for your answer; while I am yet to try it, I did read on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init that "...When not specified, Git will use permissions reported by umask" - so I was wondering if you'd have some thoughts into why git in this case.appeared to have ignored the existing umask

Comment: Seems that `git init` and `git pull` use different umask perhaps because `git init` was issued in the command line while `git pull` is performed bu Jenkins without reading bash interactive config.

Comment: that supposition sounds like a logical cause of the issue, although I don't know that could occur. git init was indeed on the command while git pull isn't. Should this be the case though, would you recommend the same solution or would you suggest an alternative? Thanks for your help with this again

Comment: Perhaps `umask` could be configured in Jenkins. Or source `~/.bashrc` somewhere before running `git pull`. Something like `source ~/.bashrc && git pull`. Or even `umask 002 && git pull`.